# Greek writing in LaTeX

Tags: input-encodings, greek

I have a problem using Texmaker when I am trying to write in Greek.

The starting commands I use in my document are

```
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
```

but when it comes to translation I get an error that says `File iso-8859-7.def not found`.

What should I do? I have tried other commands as well to write in Greek but nothing works.

[image: output]

The log file can be found [here](http://file:///C:/Users/Vasilis/Desktop/%CE%9A%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B7%CF%83%CF%80%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B1.log).

```
    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.5.3)  3 MAY 2015 18:48
entering extended mode
**Καλησπέρα.tex
(C:\Users\Vasilis\Desktop\Καλησπέρα.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty"
Package: babel 2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg"
File: bblopts.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
)
("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\generic\babel\english.ldf"
Language: english 2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system

("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\generic\babel\babel.def"
File: babel.def 2008/07/08 v3.8m Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)
("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\generic\babel\greek.ldf"
Language: greek 2005/03/30 v1.3l Greek support from the babel system

Loading the definitions for the Greek font encoding
("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\generic\babel\lgrenc.def"
File: lgrenc.def 2008/06/17 v2.3 Greek Encoding
)))
("C:\Program Files\latex\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty"
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15


! LaTeX Error: File `iso-8859-7.def' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: def)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.131 \endinput


*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 611 strings out of 493921
 7322 string characters out of 3149282
 60064 words of memory out of 3000000
 3973 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,0n,20p,203b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `utf8`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a complete minimal example? In any case, it's much better to switch to UTF-8.

Comment: i tried utf8 but it appears error again i don't know what is going wrong

Comment: Check if your editor saves your code in utf8 format (it should by default).

Comment: it does but there are no results i get only errors

Comment: As already mentioned, then give us a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to work with. Also, the log file would to nice to have.

Comment: i uploaded a photo of the editor

Comment: The image is good, but, please, also add the code to your question.

Comment: What's with the close votes here: seems clear enough to me to work with (still need more info but that will come I think).

Comment: Looks like something is not right with your TeX system: file `iso-8859-7.def` should be available. I see you are using MiKTeX: you can use its Package Manager to search for that file for installation.

Comment: i did it before and during the installation there is an error with some gibberish words

Comment: @Vasilis Try a different MiKTeX server or wait a day or so for this to 'go away'. (It's not a TeX issue _per se_ and these MiKTeX server things do come and go.)

Comment: how do i change server? if i install tomorrow the package it will be ok you think?

Comment: what about when i use the utf8 package instead of the iso-8859-7 should i wait for that as well because i think it is the same problem